# Trouble replicating a stack buffer overflow exploit

Tags: c, stack, overflow

I am having trouble replicating the stack buffer overflow example given by OWASP [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_overflow_attack).

Here is my attempt:

```
$ cat test.c
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  void doit(void)
  {
          char buf[8];

          gets(buf);
          printf("%s\n", buf);
  }

  int main(void)
  {
          printf("So... The End...\n");
          doit();
          printf("or... maybe not?\n");

          return 0;
  }



$ gcc test.c -o test -fno-stack-protection -ggdb

$ objdump -d test # omitted irrelevant parts i think
000000000040054c <doit>:
  40054c:       55                      push   %rbp
  40054d:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400550:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  400554:       48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  400558:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40055b:       e8 d0 fe ff ff          callq  400430 <gets@plt>
  400560:       48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  400564:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400567:       e8 a4 fe ff ff          callq  400410 <puts@plt>
  40056c:       c9                      leaveq
  40056d:       c3                      retq

000000000040056e <main>:
  40056e:       55                      push   %rbp
  40056f:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400572:       bf 4c 06 40 00          mov    $0x40064c,%edi
  400577:       e8 94 fe ff ff          callq  400410 <puts@plt>
  40057c:       e8 cb ff ff ff          callq  40054c <doit>
  400581:       bf 5d 06 40 00          mov    $0x40065d,%edi
  400586:       e8 85 fe ff ff          callq  400410 <puts@plt>
  40058b:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400590:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400591:       c3                      retq # this is where i took my overflow value from
  400592:       90                      nop
  400593:       90                      nop
  400594:       90                      nop
  400595:       90                      nop
  400596:       90                      nop
  400597:       90                      nop
  400598:       90                      nop
  400599:       90                      nop
  40059a:       90                      nop
  40059b:       90                      nop
  40059c:       90                      nop
  40059d:       90                      nop
  40059e:       90                      nop
  40059f:       90                      nop

$ perl -e 'print "A"x12 ."\x91\x05\x40"' | ./test
So... The End...
AAAAAAAAAAAA▒@
or... maybe not? # this shouldn't be outputted
```

Why isn't this working? I'm assuming that the memory address that I am supposed to insert is the `retq` from `<main>`.

My goal is to figure out how to do a stack buffer overflow that calls a function elsewhere in the program. Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: What do you mean by *I am having trouble replicating the stack buffer overflow *? What input are you giving to `gets`?

Comment: @ouah `perl -e 'print "A"x12 ."\x91\x05\x40"' | ./test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Windows & MSVC but you should get the idea.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void someFunc()
{
    puts("wow, we should never get here :|");
}

// MSVC inlines this otherwise
void __declspec(noinline) doit(void)
{
    char buf[8];

    gets(buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("So... The End...\n");
    doit();
    printf("or... maybe not?\n");

    return 0;
}
```

(Note: I had to compile it with `/OPT:NOREF` to force MSVC not to remove "unused" code and `/GS-` to turn off stack checks)

Now, let's open it in my favorite disassembler:
[image]

We'd like to exploit the `gets` vulnerability so the execution jumps to `someFunc`. We can see that its address is `001D1000`, so if we can write enough bytes past the buffer to overwrite the return address, we'll be good. Let's take a look at the stack when `gets` is called:

[image]

As we can see, there's 8 bytes of our stack allocated buffer (`buf`), 4 bytes of some stuff (actually the `PUSH`ed EBP), and the return address. Thus, we need to write 12 bytes of whatever and then our 4 byte return address (`001D1000`) to "hijack" the execution flow. Let's do just that - we'll prepare an input file with the bytes we need using a hex editor:

[image]

And indeed, when we run the program with that input, we get this:

[image]

After it prints that line, it will crash with an access violation since there was some garbage on the stack. However, there's nothing stopping you from carefully analyzing the code and preparing such bytes in your input that the program will appear to function as normal (we could overwrite the next bytes with the address of `ExitProcess`, so that `someFunc` would jump there).

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept but I am still having trouble getting this to work when I try to replicate the OWASP example, or in fact any example.

Comment: So I have since discovered that the reason I was having trouble is because the stored EIP isn't always 4 bytes from the end of `buf`. What causes that and how can I detect that?

Comment: @SebastianKing You seem to be compiling for 64 bit, so that could be the reason. That said, the return address doesn't always have to be like in my example here; it depends on the compiler, its settings, etc. In your case `buf` is 16 bytes long (64 bit alignment), then 8 bytes for RBP, then the return address.

Comment: Oh, I see, how do I tell how far the EIP is from the stack pointer in the future?

Comment: @SebastianKing Well, you can just statically analyze the diassembly like I did in this case, or, if you're lazy, start your favorite debugger, break at the desired location and examine the stack window (under Windows, I can wholeheartedly recommend OllyDbg, under Linux, not sure).

Comment: @SebastianKing Also, in x64, it's RIP, not EIP.